# How to use Content Provider and Content Observer in API Level 8?

Tags: android, api, android-contentprovider, android-support-library

I want to use `Content Provider` and `Content Observer` from the Api level-8. I am able to create this in Api-15 (ICS). but i have to support my app from Api-8.

If i mention android:minSdkVersion="8" like this i am getting this errors
`Class requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.content.Loader`.

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class TodosOverviewActivity extends ListActivity implements     LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;     
private ConverstationsAdapter adapter;
private EditText Enter_Text; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.todo_list);
    this.getListView().setDividerHeight(2);
    fillData();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    Enter_Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg);

    findViewById(R.id.send_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            SendInfo();
        }
    });
}

private void SendInfo() {

    String msg = Enter_Text.getText().toString().trim();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TodoTable.COLUMN_RECEIVER, "Reddy");
    values.put(TodoTable.COLUMN_SENDER, "RA");
    values.put(TodoTable.COLUMN_MSG, msg);

    getContentResolver().insert(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case DELETE_ID:
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/" + info.id);
        getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
        fillData();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}

private void fillData() {  
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);   // error here   
    adapter = new ConverstationsAdapter(TodosOverviewActivity.this, null );
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
}

// Creates a new loader after the initLoader () call
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = { TodoTable.COLUMN_ID, TodoTable.COLUMN_MSG };
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
            MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    adapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // data is not available anymore, delete reference
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
}
```

Comment: I think question should be how to use `Loader` in `API8` because nothing wrong with `ContentProvider` and `ContentObserver`.

Comment: ya it's working fine in API-15 i want support my app from Minsdk -8;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `android.support.v4.content.Loader`

*Edit*

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;

...

public class YourClass implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> ...
...

@Override public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = { TodoTable.COLUMN_ID, TodoTable.COLUMN_MSG };
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
        MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}
```

pay attention to *LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<**Cursor**>*

*Edit*
 In any way read this [CursorLoader tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/), as for me - I prefer restartLoader() not initLoader() as in tutorial.

*Edit*

Rewrite your Activity with help of fragments(wired version):

package de.vogella.android.todos;

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class TodosOverviewActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public static class TodosOverviewListFragment extends ListFragment
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private ConverstationsAdapter adapter;
    private EditText Enter_Text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        adapter = new ConverstationsAdapter(getActivity(), null);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        String[] projection = { TodoTable.COLUMN_ID, TodoTable.COLUMN_MSG };
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null,
                null);
        return cursorLoader;
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor data) {
        adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    TodosOverviewListFragment fragment = new TodosOverviewListFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(fragment, "xx");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

manifest:
     `uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15"`

add Support package to your project (project->Android Tools)

Comment: I was imported  `android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
android.support.v4.content.Loader;` , still i am getting this error `The return type is incompatible with LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>.onCreateLoader(int, Bundle)`

Comment: are you speaking about android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager and its stuff ?

Comment: problem with stuff also, i was updated my Question with code and error.

Comment: i got some stuff was working, here one small error Edit my code in the Question. if that was not sufficient let me know.i will post some more code.

Comment: this method fillData(), what type is it's class?

Comment: as for me I'd better use cursorLoader.restartLoader(someId); not initLoader(...)

Comment: Here someid means what i have to pass

Comment: it doesnt metter in your case let it be 1 or 20, it some kind of "mark" for Async Task Lader (see LoaderHelper in android src). This id will be passed to public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) as id argument

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17641/discussion-between-ra-and-rajareddy-polamreddy)

Comment: @ra i think the answer is not valid ;) because its not about loaders, but about ContentObservers.

To give another technology is not what is asked. right?

Answer (score 0):

Both `contentobserver` and `contentprovider` are present in api 8. So you can use them without any problems.
Seeing your error, you are trying to use `Loader`. You can safely use `AsyncTask` and do cursor loading in doinbackground instead of using Loader. Loader was introduced in API 11

So Remove usage of android.content.Loader , you should be able to build

Comment: is it possible to use Loader from API-8.

Comment: like ra has said use [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) and you can import android.support.v4.content.Loader